# Compass Heading information in RealityKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, arkit, realitykit

I'm new to SwiftUI, and I've learned some basics of my project's **RealityKit** and **ARKit**. I just want to display an arrow that always faces towards the north, or at least get heading information displayed as text when I open the camera (AR Experience).

Waiting for someone to solve this fundamental problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to create AR experience that depends on device's geo position.

### Reality Composer

[image]

### Code

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import ARKit

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
       
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        arView.cameraMode = .ar
        arView.automaticallyConfigureSession = false

        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        config.worldAlignment = .gravityAndHeading       // case = 1
        arView.session.run(config)
        
        let arrowScene = try! Experience.loadNorth()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(arrowScene)
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```

---

```
struct ContentView : View {
        
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ARViewContainer().ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}
```

### Settings

On device, go to `Settings`–`Privacy`–`Location Services`–`On`. After that, in Xcode, append `Privacy LocationUsageDescription` and `LocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and then `CameraUsageDescription` keys in `info` tab.

[image]

Comment: this will point where the horizontal plane anchor is pointing

Comment: @masaldana2, This code works great for me.